# Why global scope can not be accessed in this case?

Tags: javascript

I faced this issue recently. I could pass the problem, but I didn't get the concept behind it.
If you try the snippet, you see what's going on. Can someone explain it?

```js
function func1() {
  console.log('Func1 executed.');
};

const func2 = () => {
  console.log('Func2 executed.');
};

const test = () => {
  window['func1'](); //Working
  window['func2'](); //Not working
};
```

```css
button {
  width: 200px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: large;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to top right, gray, silver);
  color: white;
  border-radius: 7px;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 7px silver;
  text-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

```html
<button onclick='test()'>Execute</button>
```

Comment: That’s informative. Thanks. @Rounin answer is more clear and shorter IMO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The straightforward answer is:

Global variables initialised with `let` and `const` do not become properties of `window`.

See:

## `const`

> Global constants do **not** become properties of the `window` object, unlike `var` variables

**Source:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const

and:

## `let`

> Just like `const` the `let` does *not* create properties of the `window` object when declared globally (in the top-most scope).

**Source:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very experienced with JS, but I believe is because the first one is actually a function that can be reused multiple time, where the second one is lambda function with the purpose to returning and storing a value (but not recompute) into the func2 var.

Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: This is not true. `func2` is also a callable function, it does not hold the value of executing the function.

Comment: @BrianThompson interesting, thanks for your correction.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are really calling a value/variable (`const func2 =`  could end with a int for example.) You need to pass a function itself int tohe format `window[Functioname]()`.

You can do this through 2nd degree function calling, see below.

Nice button by the way.

```js
function func1() {
  console.log('Func1 executed.');
};
const func2 = () => {
  console.log('Func2 executed.');
};


function func3(){
  func2();
}
const test = () => {
  window['func1'](); //Working
  window['func3'](); //Working
  window['func2'](); //Not working
};
```

```css
button {
  width: 200px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: large;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to top right, gray, silver);
  color: white;
  border-radius: 7px;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 7px silver;
  text-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

```html
<button onclick='test()'>Execute</button>
```